# Concatenate two (or n) streams

Tags: node.js, stream, eventemitter

- 2 streams:

  Given readable [streams](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html) `stream1` and `stream2`, what's an idiomatic (concise) way to **get a stream containing `stream1` and `stream2` concatenated**?

  I cannot do `stream1.pipe(outStream); stream2.pipe(outStream)`, because then the stream contents are jumbled together.
- *n* streams:

  Given an [EventEmitter](http://nodejs.org/api/events.html) that emits an indeterminate number of streams, e.g.

  ```
  eventEmitter.emit('stream', stream1)
  eventEmitter.emit('stream', stream2)
  eventEmitter.emit('stream', stream3)
  ...
  eventEmitter.emit('end')
  ```

  what's an idiomatic (concise) way to **get a stream with all streams concatenated together**?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The [combined-stream](https://github.com/felixge/node-combined-stream) package concatenates streams. Example from the README:

```
var CombinedStream = require('combined-stream');
var fs = require('fs');

var combinedStream = CombinedStream.create();
combinedStream.append(fs.createReadStream('file1.txt'));
combinedStream.append(fs.createReadStream('file2.txt'));

combinedStream.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('combined.txt'));
```

I believe you have to append all streams at once. If the queue runs empty, the `combinedStream` automatically ends. See [issue #5](https://github.com/felixge/node-combined-stream/issues/5).

The [stream-stream](https://github.com/Floby/node-stream-stream) library is an alternative that has an explicit `.end`, but it's much less popular and presumably not as well-tested. It uses the streams2 API of Node 0.10 (see [this discussion](https://github.com/Floby/node-stream-stream/issues/3)).

Comment: The `combined-stream` package already supports adding source streams in callback function, so you don't have to initiate them on the start which helps saving up memory, file descriptors and etc.
Also, there is much more popular library [multistream](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multistream) which seems more tested

Comment: Does that work with audio (pcm/opus) streams?

Answer (score 35):

This can be done with vanilla Node.js

```
import { PassThrough } from 'stream'
const merge = (...streams) => {
    let pass = new PassThrough()
    for (let stream of streams) {
        const end = stream == streams.at(-1);
        pass = stream.pipe(pass, { end })
    }
    return pass
}
```

Use `streams.slice(-1)[0]` if you don't have `.at()` in your version of Node.js

Comment: what if one stream never ends, but the other one does

Comment: Just a update `pass.emit('end')` not working. Try `pass.end() `

Comment: Change `--waiting` to `waiting--`

Comment: @TomLarkworthy Is that a response to @PirateApp? If not then I don't see why one should do so as this causes the last stream to never end

Comment: This solution is nice but didn't keep the order of streams in my usage for some odd reason. Calling `merge(a, b)` produced a stream in which `b` preceded `a`. Could it be related to the fact that `b` is a stream of far less items compared to `a`, and ends first?

Answer (score 17):

This can now be easily done using async iterators

```js
async function* concatStreams(readables) {
  for (const readable of readables) {
    for await (const chunk of readable) { yield chunk }
  }
}
```

And you can use it like this

```js
const fs = require('fs')
const stream = require('stream')

const files = ['file1.txt', 'file2.txt', 'file3.txt'] 
const iterable = await concatStreams(files.map(f => fs.createReadStream(f)))

// convert the async iterable to a readable stream
const mergedStream = stream.Readable.from(iterable)
```

More info regarding async iterators: https://2ality.com/2019/11/nodejs-streams-async-iteration.html

Comment: The stream returned from `createReadStream` is not iterable.

Comment: Do you mean mergedStream? because I can iterate it without any problems https://gist.github.com/ducaale/5e3fd00a70487c98333e5fb42bc4b624

Comment: If order is not required, ss it possible to await all so it runs in in parallel and thus faster?

Comment: Sure, you can manually get the next item from the two async-iterables via `await readable.next()` and take the one that resolves first.

Comment: this option is the best on my opinion, but to typescript implementation must add `...` on signature like this
```ts
async function* concatStreams(...readables) {
```

Answer (score 9):

If you don't care about the ordering of data in the streams, a simple [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) operation should be fine in [nodejs](https://nodejs.org)!

```
const {PassThrough} = require('stream')

let joined = [s0, s1, s2, ...sN].reduce((pt, s, i, a) => {
  s.pipe(pt, {end: false})
  s.once('end', () => a.every(s => s.ended) && pt.emit('end'))
  return pt
}, new PassThrough())
```

Cheers ;)

Comment: Shouldn't you be returning something from reduce? This looks like `joined` will be undefined.

Comment: WARNING: This will cause all the streams to pipe to the PassThrough stream in parallel, without any regards toward the ordering of the data, more than likely corrupting your data.

Comment: @LeonLi which is indeed the purpose of this approach. If you want to preserve the order you might pass an initial value different than PassThrough to your reduce function ;)

Comment: @LeonLi If you're wondering when you might not care about data ordering, I'm using this to pipe records (ie. objects) to a data store. Each record is indexed/ordered by an internal field, so I don't really care about insertion order.

Comment: @Ivo This question asks about *concatenation*. Most readers arriving in this QA would therefore care about ordering. This answer silently misleads those readers because the streams successfully get passed through, but unless you check the output you'll never know that it also jumbled all of your data (which the question specifically asks to avoid in the first place!). I urge you to add this information to the answer body.

Comment: No such thing as `stream.ended`. You'll have to set `s.ended = true` inside the end event handler.

Comment: Since writable streams don't have an `'end'` event, I assume this is only meant to work for readable streams. As @ffxsam said, `s.ended` doesn't exist. Replacing `s.ended` with `s.readableEnded` worked for me. Docs: https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html

Answer (score 6):

In vanilla nodejs using ECMA 15+ and combining the good answers of **Ivo** and **Feng**.

The [`PassThrough`](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_passthrough) class is a trivial [`Transform`](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_transform) stream which does not modify the stream in any way.

```
const { PassThrough } = require('stream');

const concatStreams = (streamArray, streamCounter = streamArray.length) => streamArray
  .reduce((mergedStream, stream) => {
    // pipe each stream of the array into the merged stream
    // prevent the automated 'end' event from firing
    mergedStream = stream.pipe(mergedStream, { end: false });
    // rewrite the 'end' event handler
    // Every time one of the stream ends, the counter is decremented.
    // Once the counter reaches 0, the mergedstream can emit its 'end' event.
    stream.once('end', () => --streamCounter === 0 && mergedStream.emit('end'));
    return mergedStream;
  }, new PassThrough());
```

Can be used like this:

```
const mergedStreams = concatStreams([stream1, stream2, stream3]);
```

Comment: this pipes the streams before they are done, jumbling them; this is exactly what the original question was asking about avoiding - how to concatenate, not jumble, the streams.

Comment: to avoid this, you should stream.pipe the next one after the previous one fires the 'end' event

Answer (score 3):

You might be able to make it more concise, but here's one that works:

```
var util = require('util');
var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;

function ConcatStream(streamStream) {
  EventEmitter.call(this);
  var isStreaming = false,
    streamsEnded = false,
    that = this;

  var streams = [];
  streamStream.on('stream', function(stream){
    stream.pause();
    streams.push(stream);
    ensureState();
  });

  streamStream.on('end', function() {
    streamsEnded = true;
    ensureState();
  });

  var ensureState = function() {
    if(isStreaming) return;
    if(streams.length == 0) {
      if(streamsEnded)
        that.emit('end');
      return;
    }
    isStreaming = true;
    streams[0].on('data', onData);
    streams[0].on('end', onEnd);
    streams[0].resume();
  };

  var onData = function(data) {
    that.emit('data', data);
  };

  var onEnd = function() {
    isStreaming = false;
    streams[0].removeAllListeners('data');
    streams[0].removeAllListeners('end');
    streams.shift();
    ensureState();
  };
}

util.inherits(ConcatStream, EventEmitter);
```

We keep track of state with `streams` (the queue of streams;`push` to the back and `shift` from the front), `isStreaming`, and `streamsEnded`.  When we get a new stream, we push it, and when a stream ends, we stop listening and shift it.  When the stream of streams ends, we set `streamsEnded`.

On each of these events, we check the state we're in.  If we're already streaming (piping a stream), we do nothing.  If the queue is empty and `streamsEnded` is set, we emit the `end` event.  If there is something in the queue, we resume it and listen to its events.

*Note that `pause` and `resume` are advisory, so some streams may not behave correctly, and would require buffering.  This exercise is left to the reader.

Having done all of this, I would do the `n=2` case by constructing an `EventEmitter`, creating a `ConcatStream` with it, and emitting two `stream` events followed by an `end` event.  I'm sure it could be done more concisely, but we may as well use what we've got.

Comment: Thanks Aaron! I was kinda hoping there'd be some existing library so I can solve it in three lines. If there isn't, I'm thinking I might extract your solution into a package. Can I use your code under an MIT license?

Comment: Ah, found the stream-stream library. See my answer.

Comment: @JoLiss I also looked for something first, but I failed to find that option.  You can certainly use my code in a library if you still want to.

Answer (score 3):

https://github.com/joepie91/node-combined-stream2 is a drop-in Streams2-compatible replacement for the combined-stream module (which is described above.)  It automatically wraps Streams1 streams.

Example code for combined-stream2:

```
var CombinedStream = require('combined-stream2');
var fs = require('fs');

var combinedStream = CombinedStream.create();
combinedStream.append(fs.createReadStream('file1.txt'));
combinedStream.append(fs.createReadStream('file2.txt'));

combinedStream.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('combined.txt'));
```

Answer (score 2):

Both of the most upvoted answers here aren't working with asynchronous streams because they just pipe things on regardless whether the source stream is ready to produce. I had to combine in-memory string streams with data feed from a database, and the database content was always at the end of the resulting stream because it takes a second to get a db response. Here's what I ended up writing for my purposes.

```
export function joinedStream(...streams: Readable[]): Readable {
  function pipeNext(): void {
    const nextStream = streams.shift();
    if (nextStream) {
      nextStream.pipe(out, { end: false });
      nextStream.on('end', function() {
        pipeNext();
      });
    } else {
      out.end();
    }
  }
  const out = new PassThrough();
  pipeNext();
  return out;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[streamee.js](https://github.com/atamborrino/streamee.js) is a set of stream transformers and composers based on node 1.0+ streams and include a concatenate method:

```
var stream1ThenStream2 = streamee.concatenate([stream1, stream2]);
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out. That's Node 0.10 I assume?

Comment: Yes Node 0.10, but you can wrap old-style streams into 0.10+ streams as written in the README

Answer (score 0):

The below code worked for me :). Have taken the inputs from all the answers given earlier

```
  const pipeStreams = (streams) => {
  const out = new PassThrough()
  // Piping the first stream to the out stream
  // Also prevent the automated 'end' event of out stream from firing
  streams[0].pipe(out, { end: false })
  for (let i = 0; i < streams.length - 2; i++) {
    // On the end of each stream (until the second last) pipe the next stream to the out stream
    // Prevent the automated 'end' event of out stream from firing
    streams[i].on('end', () => {
      streams[i + 1].pipe(out, { end: false })
    })
  }
  // On the end of second last stream pipe the last stream to the out stream.
  // Don't prevent the 'end flag from firing'
  streams[streams.length - 2].on('end', () => {
    streams[streams.length - 1].pipe(out)
  })
  return out
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Nisha provided my favourite solution to this problem. Some of the solutions didn't remove the end event which caused some issues when doing audio stream merging. However, he forgot to handle the obvious case of when there is just one stream. Thank you so much for the well-thought solution Nisha!

```
const pipeStreams = (streams: Stream[]): Stream => {
    //If there is only one stream, return that stream
    if (streams.length == 1) return streams[0];
    const out = new PassThrough()
    // Piping the first stream to the out stream
    // Also prevent the automated 'end' event of out stream from firing
    streams[0].pipe(out, { end: false })
    for (let i = 0; i < streams.length - 2; i++) {
        // On the end of each stream (until the second last) pipe the next stream to the out stream
        // Prevent the automated 'end' event of out stream from firing
        streams[i].on('end', () => {
            streams[i + 1].pipe(out, { end: false })
        })
    }
    // On the end of second last stream pipe the last stream to the out stream.
    // Don't prevent the 'end flag from firing'
    streams[streams.length - 2].on('end', () => {
        streams[streams.length - 1].pipe(out)
    })
    return out
}
```