# How to convert 2 or more streams into one single stream

Tags: node.js

If I am receiving multiple stream data at a point, how can I convert all that data into a single stream? This is a bit hard to explain but it looks sort of like this

```
Stream 1 --------
                  \
Stream 2 --------  -- Point -> Final Stream
                  /
Stream 3 --------
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please clarify whether this expects the first stream to be drained first, then continue consuming from stream two, and so forth. Or must the merging interleave the chunks?

Comment: I want to merge them

Comment: By interleaving chunks of the input streams?

Comment: yes that'd be fine

Comment: Then this answer is what you are looking for https://stackoverflow.com/a/56887262/1149632. This will interleave the incoming chunks in a mangled FIFO manner.